# Números que más se repite en un arreglo bidimensional

Tags: c#, .net

En un arreglo  bidimensional en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

```
int[,] x = new int[4, 3]
```

Necesito sacar los números que más se repiten.

Comment: Tienes que dar mas condiciones, por ejemplo que pasa si hay varios números con igual número máximo de repeticiones

Answer (score 5):

Este código:

```
var resultado = Enumerable.Range(0, x.GetLength(0) * x.GetLength(1))
    .Select(n => x[n / x.GetLength(1), n % x.GetLength(1)])
    .GroupBy(n => n, (n, g) => new { Numero = n, Cantidad = g.Count() })
    .GroupBy(a => a.Cantidad, (cant, g) => new { Cantidad = cant, Numeros = g.Select(i => i.Numero) })
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.Cantidad)
    .First()
    .Numeros;
```

Te dará una lista de los números que más se repiten en x.

Para explicar línea por línea que es lo que hace...

Asumiendo el siguiente array bidimensional

```
int[,] x = new int[4, 3] { { 5, 1, 3 }, { 4, 9, 5 }, { 4, 6, 2 }, { 5, 4, 9 } };
```

La primera línea:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, x.GetLength(0) * x.GetLength(1))
```

devuelve la lista de números desde el 0 hasta el número de elementos del array bidimensional menos 1. `x.GetLength(0)` devuleve el número de elementos de la primera dimensión (4) y `x.GetLength(0)` de la segunda dimensión (3). Por lo tanto la lista va desde el `0` hasta el `4*3-1`.

[image: Enumerable.Range(0, x.GetLength(0) * x.GetLength(1))]

La sgte línea:

```
.Select(n => x[n / x.GetLength(1), n % x.GetLength(1)])
```

obtiene los valores del arreglo bidimensional como una lista unidimensional. Esto lo hace mediante una fórmula matemática muy sencilla: la coordenada `x` corresponde a la división entera del índice del rango anterior en cuestión entre el ancho (longitud de la segunda dimensión) del arreglo bidimensional. La coordenada `y` corresponde al resto de la división entera.

[image: .Select(n => x[n / x.GetLength(1), n % x.GetLength(1)])]

La siguiente línea:

```
.GroupBy(n => n, (n, g) => new { Numero = n, Cantidad = g.Count() })
```

Agrupa los números por la cantidad de veces que se repiten. El primer lambda: `n => n` es el *key selector*, lo que le indica por que key se van a agrupar los resultados, en este caso es por el mismo número.

El segundo lambda `(n, g) => new { Numero = n, Cantidad = g.Count() })` es el *result selector*. En este caso toma dos parámetros : el número `n` y el grupo `g` con estos parámetros se arma una clase anónima con dos propiedades llamadas `Numero` y `Cantidad` donde `Numero` almacena el número `n` y `Cantidad` almacena cuantas veces se encuentra el número en el grupo.

[image: .GroupBy(n => n, (n, g) => new { Numero = n, Cantidad = g.Count() })]

La siguiente línea:

```
.GroupBy(a => a.Cantidad, (cant, g) => new { Cantidad = cant, Numeros = g.Select(i => i.Numero) })
```

intenta agrupar los números por cantidad de veces que se repiten. Esto lo hace para poder resolver el caso en que varios números tengan igual cantidad de veces que se repitan y empaten el primer puesto.

En este caso el *key selector*: `a => a.Cantidad` indica que esta vez cada elemento de la clase anónima de la línea anterior se agrupará por `Cantidad` (cantidad de veces que se repetñia el nñumero).

El *result selector*: `(cant, g) => new { Cantidad = cant, Numeros = g.Select(i => i.Numero) }` crea una nueva clase anónima con `Cantidad` igual al número de veces que se repite el número y `Numeros` que corresponden a la lista de números a los que les corresponde esa cantidad.

[image: .GroupBy(a => a.Cantidad, (cant, g) => new { Cantidad = cant, Numeros = g.Select(i => i.Numero) })]

La siguiente línea:

```
.OrderByDescending(i => i.Cantidad)
```

ordena los grupos anteriores de forma descendente tomando en cuenta la cantidad. Con lo cual el grupo con mayor cantidad de repeticiones se queda primero en la lista.

[image: .OrderByDescending(i => i.Cantidad)]

La siguiente línea:

```
.First()
```

se queda únicamente con el primer grupo que corresponde a los números que buscamos

[image: .First()]

Y finalmente la última línea:

```
.Numeros;
```

descarta la cantidad de repeticiones y nos deja únicamente con los números buscados.

[image: .Numeros;]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este codigo :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var numeros = new List<Numeros>();
        int[,] arreglo = new int[4, 3] { {1,1,1}, {1,2,2}, {2,3,3}, {3,4,4} };
        for(int x=0; x<4; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<3; y++)
            {                
                var n = numeros.SingleOrDefault(num => num.Numero==arreglo[x,y]);
                if (n==null)
                {
                    n = new Numeros();
                    n.Numero = arreglo[x,y];
                    n.Conteo = 1;
                    numeros.Add(n);
                }
                else
                {
                    n.Conteo++;
                }
            }    
        }

        foreach(var num in numeros)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Numero : {0}, Conteo : {1}", num.Numero, num.Conteo );
        }

        var maxConteo = numeros.Max(n => n.Conteo);
        var maxNumero = numeros.Where(n => n.Conteo == maxConteo).ToList();
        foreach(var num in maxNumero)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num.Numero);
        }
    }

    class Numeros
    {
        public int Numero;
        public int Conteo;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Mauricio. En este tipo de preguntas solemos esperar que quien pregunta agregue lo que hizo. No solemos solucionar tareas sin un mínimo esfuerzo de quien pregunta, pidiéndole que agregue lo que probo o hizo hasta el momento, para de ahí ayudarlo a seguir. Igual tu respuesta parece correcta. Saludos